# PHP Like System: Change Image Attribute on Displayed Listing if Record is within User Favorites(pivot table)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am attempting to develop an "add to favorites" system in which a user can "like" a book and it gets added to the pivot table(user_id and book_id go to table **book_user**). I currently have a many to many relationship set up and I loop through the list of all books(as shown in the @foreach loop in view) from my **books** table.

The question is how can I change the image shown(in the view which in this case is a div id ="heart-size") depending on whether the user has added that item to their favorites (book reference exists within the **book_user** table attributed to that user)? That is, if the book is in the user favorites display a red heart, if not leave it grey and continue listing the rest of the books.

### Tables

#### books

id | book_name | book_author | book_url

#### users

id | user_id | password

#### book_user

id | user_id(foreign key from users) | book_id(foreign key from books)

**Model** Book.php

```
class Book extends Eloquent{

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'books';

public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}}
```

**Controller** BooksController.php

```
class BooksController extends BaseController {

   protected $layout = "layouts.main";

   public function Booklist() {

    $books = Book::all();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('books.booklist', array('books' => $books));
}}
```

**View** booklist.blade.php

```
    <div class="booklist">
     <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover" width = "70">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Book Name</th>
        <th>Author Name</th>
        <th>URL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
   @foreach ($books as $book)
    <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>
           <div id ="heart-size">
              {{ HTML::link('book/like', '', array('id' => 'heart')) }}
           </div>
       </td>
       <td> {{ $book->book_name }} </td>
       <td>{{ $book->book_author}} </td>
       <td><a href="{{ $book->book_url }}">{{ $book->book_url}} </a> </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
   @endforeach
   </table>
   </div>
```

Comment: To tell you the truth your question is kind of confusing. Can you update it with more accurate info. Especially part where your question is.

Comment: Edited. If any more clarification is needed please let me know where and I will attempt to explain to the best of my abilities. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your Book model:

```
public function hasLiked($userid) {
  return in_array($userid, array_fetch($this->users->toArray(), 'id'));
}
```

And call it from your view (example):

```
@if $book->hasLiked($loggedinuserid) 
  <div id ="heart-size">
    {{ HTML::link('book/like', '', array('id' => 'heart')) }}
  </div>
@endif
```